# Wrong Loading Data when using Viewholder in BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am using BaseAdapter for loading the data in gridview. When the data is loaded to the gridview, and the user tries to scroll, I used to get incorrect data. In order to fix that I used ViewHolder. That actually fixed the issue, however, when the users click any of the data in the gridview, instead of getting the correct id from the item, all the items are returning a similar id number.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// Context context;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ViewHolder holder;
int layoutResourceId;

Event event;
EventDBAdapter eventDb;

int id;
PersianCalendar sc;
String Today;
SharedPreferences Prefrences_test;
String date, userid;
String newText = "";
String test;
int status;

MoodsDBAdapter moodsDBAdapter;
Mood mood;
ArrayList<MoodsNote> arrayMoodsNote;
MoodsNoteDBAdapter moodsNoteDBAdapter;
MoodsNote moodsNote;


public ProductAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    // this.context = context;
    eventDb = new EventDBAdapter(activity);
    event = new Event();
    moodsDBAdapter = new MoodsDBAdapter(activity);
    mood = new Mood();
    moodsNoteDBAdapter = new MoodsNoteDBAdapter(activity);
    data = d;
    // this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    Prefrences_test = activity.getSharedPreferences("temp", 0);
    date = Prefrences_test.getString("date", "");
    userid = Prefrences_test.getString("userid", "");
    sc = new PersianCalendar();
    Today = date;
    eventDb = new EventDBAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext());

    event = eventDb.getName(Today);

    try {
        arrayMoodsNote = moodsNoteDBAdapter.getItems(event.getID());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    holder = null;



    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_mood_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mood_text);
        holder.txt_id = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_id_mood);
        holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.mood_img);
        holder.linear = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.mood_layout);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    }
    holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_mood);
    //holder.txt_id.setText("");


    String titles = song.get("name");
    holder.title.setText(titles);

    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(song.get("icon"), "drawable",
            activity.getPackageName());
    holder.thumb_image.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);

    holder.txt_id.setText(song.get("id"));

    try {
        for (MoodsNote m : arrayMoodsNote) {
            int moodd = m.getMOOD();
            if (Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_id.getText().toString()) == moodd)

            {

                holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_mood_on);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    holder.thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(activity, holder.txt_id.getText().toString(), 0).show();
            status = 1;
            event = new Event();
            int tedad = eventDb.getDate(date);

            if (tedad <= 0) {

                event = new Event(userid, date);
                eventDb.insert(event);
            }

            event = eventDb.getName(date);
            moodsNote = new MoodsNote();
            id = 0;
            id = Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_id.getText().toString());
            // id = rowItem.getID();
            int tedadd = moodsNoteDBAdapter.getLastItemID(id);

            if (tedadd <= 0)

            {
                moodsNote.setMOOD(id);
                moodsNote.setEVENT(event.getID());
                moodsNoteDBAdapter.insert(moodsNote);

                holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_mood_on);
            }

            else {

                moodsNoteDBAdapter.deleteId(id);
                holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_mood);

            }

        }
    });

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView thumb_image;
    TextView txt_id, title;
    LinearLayout linear;

}
```

Comment: I think your part of "click any of the data in the gridview", ideally this `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` , it's in the other class ?

Comment: I don't use gridView.setOnItemClickListener..Beacase in My Adapter Wrote click for Imageview

Comment: Now, I suspect the data you feed to the adapter. Can you try `Log.d()` for the `HashMap<String, String> song` ?

Comment: see this image: http://p30droid.com/Uploader/do.php?img=289

Comment: id is wrong when click in each column of Gridview